# Генерация шестнадцатеричных чисел с условием

Tags: python, list, список, if

Необходимо сгенерировать список шестнадцатеричных чисел, не содержащих 0, и в которых сумма цифр не превосходит 11 в десятиричной системе.

Сам пока додумался только до этого:

```
import itertools
nums = [list(x) for x in itertools.product((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), repeat=7) if (x[-1] == x[-2])]
```

Осталось только проверку суммы, но как?

Может можно в условии if как-то прописать, что 'A' = 10, 'B' = 11 и тд?

Comment: `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F').index('A')+1` - вместо `'A'` нужный элемент

Comment: ваш код немного висит :) вам скольки значные числа нужны?

Comment: Евгений, понял суть, но не понял, как применить

Comment: Zhihar, не самый быстрый способ, соглашусь, но единственное, что пришло в голову. А нужны 11-значные числа

Comment: в 11 значных числах без нуля чтобы сумма была не больше 11 все числа должны быть ЕДИНИЦАМИ :)

Comment: Zhihar, видимо, пора уже ложиться спать (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я внес некоторые изменения в код

1. поскольку максимум может быть сумма 11, то никаких 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' нет - можно оставить, но считать будет гораздо дольше
2. я формирую обычные числа от 0 до 15 (ну вернее от 1 до 11), по ним вычисляю сумму
3. и в конце перевожу через список соответствий в буквы
4. буквы формирую в слова

зачем у вас в коде `if (x[-1] == x[-2])` я не понял, поэтому убрал, но если надо - верните

код:

```
import itertools

data = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')

nums = [''.join(map(lambda i: data[i], x)) for x in itertools.product((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,), repeat=7) if sum(x) < 12]

print(*nums)
```